# SELECT clause with exist condition

Tags: sql, oracle

Table name: RANKTITLE,RANK

```
//RANKTITLE
TITLE
--------------
TEST1
TEST2
TEST3
TEST4

//RANK
TITLE         SALARY
---------------------
TEST1         4500000
TEST2          80000
TEST3          26000
TEST4         1800000
```

So i want to display all the title except the rank with the highest salary

Output will be like:

```
TITLE         SALARY
--------------------
TEST2          80000
TEST3          26000
TEST4         1800000
```

Using this query

```
SELECT r.TITLE FROM RANKTITLE r WHERE
r.TITLE IN (SELECT TITLE FROM RANK) AND 
(SELECT MAX(SALARY) FROM RANK WHERE r.TITLE=p.TITLE AND SALARY < MAX(SALARY));
```

I can't get the output i want. isn't any mistake here?

Comment: What if two titles have an equally high salary? Are they both excluded?

Comment: Also, are there titles in `RANKTITLE` which may not exist in `RANK`? Should they be displayed as well?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yes. both also excluded

Comment: Wait, is that "yes" to the second question, or the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this:

```
SELECT r.TITLE, r.SALARY
FROM RANKTITLE r
WHERE r.SALARY < (SELECT MAX(s.SALARY) FROM RANK s)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT r.TITLE, salary FROM RANK r WHERE
salary not in (SELECT MAX(SALARY) FROM RANK);
```

If you have only one record with highest rank, only it will be exluded.
If you have more than one record with highest rank, all will be exluded.

```
select title from (
SELECT TITLE, rownum rnum FROM RANK  
ORDER by salary desc, title)
where rnum <> 1;
```

will exclude only unlucky first record. You don't even need RANKTITLE unless there would be some more fields that you want to grab.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select r.title,r.salary from rank r
except
select r1.title,(select max(s.salary) from rank s)
from rank r1
```